# How to convert list into a string separated with commas?

Tags: python

I have a list, `L1 = ['T51', 'T52']`. How can convert this into `T51`, `T52` and pass it to a variable?

Comment: Use the `string.join()` method.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much and thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 9):

Try the built in join method. Like so:

```
L1 = ['T51', 'T52'] 
string = " ,".join(L1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Douglas Tyler Gordon. Appreciate it !